# Can I prove n^2 - n + 1 prime for all even n?

Tags: prime-numbers

I was playing around with numbers the other day and realized that the first few values for $n(n - 1) + 1$ are prime. Now, I also quickly realized that not all values are prime ($n = 5$ results in 21, which is not prime), but I also noticed that all of the values for which the formula doesn't result in a prime are odd.  I wrote up a quick python script, and since checking $n < 100,000,000$ hasn't provided an even counterexample, I was wondering if I could somehow prove or disprove the hypothesis that, for all even $n$, $n^2 - n + 1$ is prime.

I am aware of Goldbach's proof [(mention of it)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html) that for any polynomial, not all of its outputs can be prime, but I don't think that applies if the input is restricted to to just even integers.

Python 3.6.7 code I used:

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import count, islice

n=0
m=100000000
q=0
p=1
j=0

for n in islice(count(1), m):
    if (n % 2):
        p = 0
    else:
        q = n * (n - 1) + 1
        p = n > 1 and all(n % j for j in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n) + 1)))
    if (p): print(n, p)
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27946768/) to source of method of checking primality.

Comment: $n=10?{{{{}}}}$

Comment: Goldbach's proof applies to $f(2n)$ too.

Comment: Or $n=8$. $\quad $

Comment: checking wether an integer is prime by using float point arithmetic is a bit risky

Comment: If $p(n)$ is a polynomial with prime values at all the even integers then $q(n)=p(2n)$ is prime for all integers.

Comment: $8^2-8+1=57=3\times19$

Comment: It is known that none polynomial can give only primesand you r example is $x^2-x+1$

Comment: @Piquito No it's not that $f(x).\,$  Rather it is $f(2x)\,$ as I remarked above.

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial and $|p(a)|>2$, then $p(a+kp(a))\equiv p(a)\equiv0\pmod(p(a))$, for all $k$. Since polynomials only have finitely many roots $p(a+kp(a))$ cannot be always equal to $\pm p(a)$. So, for infinitely many $k$ it is going to be a non-trivial factor of $p(a)$.

Comment: Something is wrong with your code if $n=6k+2$ then $n^2-n+1=$
$(6k+2)^2-(6k+2)+1=$
$36k^2+24k+4-6k-2+1=$
$36k^2+18k+3=$
$3(12k^2+6k+1)$

So if $n$ is of the form $6k+2$, then $n^2-n+1$ is divisible by three.

Comment: If $p(n)$ is your polynomial, then $q(n)=p(2n)$  is another polynomial, and Goldbach shows that $q(n)$ cannot always be prime.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I wondered if something was wrong.  Thanks also for explaining that $q(n)=p(2n)$, and thus Goldbach's proof still applies.

Comment: @Adren it would appear that that was my mistake.

Comment: +1. No idea why it was at -2. It's still a great question. I also noticed you followed my Materials Modeling proposal. We are now in the commitment stage and it would be very very helpful if you could click commit! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=MGFkOGRlMTg1ODg2NTUxZDQ1MDVjZmQyOTg1ZDcxODQzMjc0OGIyMjBhZDM4ZDQ5MzM0MWE1YzZhNDBjMzhlYfHJBfp5EvPDPybryqjeDgXYucHU-wUv4jp4j6imjIfF0 Only 2.7% of the people fulfill commitment on new proposals anyway so it doesn't matter if you can't participate much, but it would be very very helpful if you can commit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. A simple search in Python gives counterexamples of
$$n=8, 10, 12, 14, 20, 24, 26, 30, 32, 36, 38, 40, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 62, 64, 66, 68,\dots$$
which have corresponding composite values of
$$n^2-n+1=3\cdot19, 7\cdot13, 7\cdot19, 3\cdot61, 3\cdot127, 7\cdot79, 3\cdot7\cdot31, 13\cdot67, 3\cdot331, 13\cdot97,  \dots$$

Here is the code I used by the way:

```
#Returns a list of all primes less than or equal to Max
def ListPrimes(Max):
    if Max <= 1:
        return []
    Primes = [True for i in range(Max+1)] 

    for PrimeIndex in range(2, Max+1): 
        if (Primes[PrimeIndex] == True):
            Primes[PrimeIndex]=PrimeIndex
            PrimeIndex2 = PrimeIndex * 2
            while(PrimeIndex2 <= Max): 
                Primes[PrimeIndex2] = False
                PrimeIndex2 += PrimeIndex
    return [p for p in Primes if p!= False][2:]

print([i for i in range(2,100,2) if not ((i*i-i+1) in ListPrimes(10000))])
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I was missing something.